# Requesting OAuth Token from Zoom API Shortens the access_token attribute, but does not in Postman

Tags: c#, zoom-sdk, system.net.httpwebrequest

The access_token is always 632 characters long, and when I test it in Postman it works fine

Postman Code:

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
namespace HelloWorldApplication {
  class HelloWorld {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var client = new RestClient("https://zoom.us/oauth/token?account_id=VfdA06Q9TQe31jH7oRutuQ&grant_type=account_credentials");
      client.Timeout = -1;
      var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
      request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ####");
      request.AddHeader("Cookie", "####");
      var body = @"";
      request.AddParameter("text/plain", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);
      IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
      Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
  }
}
```

I have a limitation that prevents me from using RestSharp. As such, I am using System.Net.Http in my application, but the access_token is always 533 characters long. I get unauthorized response whenever I use that token which is what alerted me that something may be wrong with it.

System.Net.Http Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp_Test_ZoomCreateMeeting
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get current token age
        
             // Get the get credentials


            // Build the request body
            var authRequestBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "####"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "####")
        });

            // Set up the HTTP client
            var authClient = new HttpClient();
            authClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://zoom.us/");



            // Send the request and get the response
            HttpResponseMessage authResponse = authClient.PostAsync("oauth/token", authRequestBody).Result;

            string content = authResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            long contentLength = authResponse.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;


            string responseContent = authResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // Parse the JSON response
            JObject jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseContent);


            // Create an instance of JsonSerializerSettings and set the ReferenceLoopHandling property to Ignore
            JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            serializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            // Serialize the jsonResponse object using the JsonSerializerSettings object
            string serializedJsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponse, serializerSettings);

            // Extract the access_token property (value<t>)
            string currentToken = jsonResponse["access_token"].Value<string>();           


            Console.WriteLine("Current Token: " + currentToken);        
            
        }


    }
}
```

Any ideas on a solution here?

I tried to request an OAuth token from the Zoom API, and though I received one, the access_token attribute is being cut short

Answer (score 1):

Although this thread is older, with Zoom JWT App Type deprecating soon, it seems that this thread could gain traction in the near future. The following uses Zoom Server-to-Server Auth, but can be adjusted for Zoom OAuth.

To begin,
Account ID, Client ID, and Client Secret are needed.
This can be found in [Created Apps → Your App → App Credentials].

A valid Zoom Access Token takes the form of:

```
public class ZoomAccessToken
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }

}
```

It gets a little confusing reading Zoom API [https://developers.zoom.us/docs/internal-apps/s2s-oauth/], but mapping a ZoomAccessToken object via a HTTP request boils down to this:

1. Account ID
2. Base64 encoded Client ID and Client Secret
3. Host

The following code is currently implemented in my Zoom Server-to-Server Auth Application to retrieve a valid Zoom Access Token, for reference:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

private void GetAccessToken()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://zoom.us/oauth/token");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Empty);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{config.GetValue<string>("Zoom:clientID")}:{config.GetValue<string>("Zoom:clientSecret")}")));
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "account_credentials" },
        { "account_id", "your_account_id" }
     
    });
    request.Headers.Host = "zoom.us";

    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var token = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ZoomAccessToken>(content);
        this.accessToken = token;

    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the error
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve access token: {response.ReasonPhrase}");

    }

}
```

Before using the Zoom Access Token (ex. getting Zoom user information), ensure your Zoom Scopes are correct [Created Apps → Your App → Scopes]

Zoom Access Token Usage:

```
/*
* SCOPES
* /user:read:admin
* /phone_call_control:read:admin
* /phone:read:admin
*/

public class LockedPageUsers
{
    public int page_count { get; set; }
    public int page_number { get; set; }
    public int page_size { get; set; }
    public int total_records { get; set; }
    public string next_page_token { get; set; }
    public List<ZoomUser> users { get; set; }

}

public class ZoomUser
{
    public string account_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string phone_number { get; set; }

}

private List<ZoomUser> GetUsers()
{
    List<ZoomUser>ret = new List<ZoomUser>();
    GetAccessToken();
    string nextPageToken = "";

    while (nextPageToken != null)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/?page_size=300&next_page_token={nextPageToken}");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Empty);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.accessToken.access_token);
        request.Headers.Host = "api.zoom.us";

        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            // Zoom API uses pagination, [currentPagedUsers] holds the deserialized page
            var currentPagedUsers = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LockedPageUsers>(content);

            foreach (var user in currentPagedUsers.users)
            {
                ret.Add(user);
                     
            }
            // Zoom API uses pagination, [nextPageToken] holds the token for iterating to the next page
            nextPageToken = currentPagedUsers.next_page_token;
            // If [nextPageToken] is null, pagination has reached its limit
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageToken)) nextPageToken = null;

        }
        else break;

    }
    return ret;

}
```